# apache server stop working

Tags: apache-2.2, zend-framework, xampp

My zend application stop apache server. It was working fine on Xampp 1.7.4 but for some reason i have to shift my all projects on xampp 1.7.0. So whenever i tried to open my application in browser i got "Apache server stop working" window only for my zend project. Other projects(cakephp) are working fine.

I checked my log files and found these line:

> [Tue Jun 21 10:00:54 2011] [warn] pid file D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:00:54 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:00:54 2011] [notice] Digest: done
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:00:58 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:00:58 2011] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:00:58 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2888
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:00:59 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:00:59 2011] [notice] Digest: done
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:01:00 2011] [notice] Child 2888: Child process is running
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:01:00 2011] [notice] Child 2888: Acquired the start mutex.
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:01:00 2011] [notice] Child 2888: Starting 250 worker threads.
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:01:00 2011] [notice] Child 2888: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:01:00 2011] [notice] Child 2888: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:28:45 2011] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:12 2011] [warn] pid file D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten --  Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:12 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:12 2011] [notice] Digest: done
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:13 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:13 2011] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:13 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5040
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:14 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:14 2011] [notice] Digest: done
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:15 2011] [notice] Child 5040: Child process is running
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:15 2011] [notice] Child 5040: Acquired the start mutex.
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:15 2011] [notice] Child 5040: Starting 250 worker threads.
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:15 2011] [notice] Child 5040: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
>
> [Tue Jun 21 10:34:15 2011] [notice] Child 5040: Starting thread to listen on port 80.

i read somewhere in the forum that if i copy 2 dll files libmysql.dll and php5apache.dll inside windows/system32 folder then it will solve "Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting." problem. But it is not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution that php programs using PDO crashed apache. Download php-5.2.13-Win32-VC6-x86.zip and unzip, then copy libmysql.dll into xampp\apache\bin and xampp\php. Restart apache. Problem Solved :)